# Effects of Solar Distributed Generators on Utility Grid

Tags: solar-energy, power-grid, renewable-energy

The figure Below is a test block diagram that I would like to model and simulate in DigSILENT PowerFactory Software to analyze the effects of SDGs on the utility grid’s Power losses, Voltage Fluctuations, Power Quality and Reliability! Do you all think this block diagram is correct and can be used to analyze effects of SDGs on the utility grid’s Power losses, Voltage Fluctuations, Power Quality and Reliability?
[image]

Comment: Why is your ground labelled load?

Comment: @tuskiomi The arrow is proper notation for a single-line diagram.

Comment: Don't those arrows usually point out, not down? hmm

Comment: @tuskiomi Nope. Not sure what you mean by "out". That's the proper symbol for a load. If the line were coming from the point, that would mean utility power connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about distributed generation particularly, it seems to me that the model should include the distribution system with the generation located at some point(s) on the primary distribution feeder.

It seems to me that Power losses, Voltage Fluctuations, Power Quality could be studied using a power flow model. Depending on the configuration of the distribution system and the distributed generator, you might need to consider an unbalanced three-phase model so that you can include single-phase loads. I think that these studies will need to consider the range of possible distributed generator output and system loads. I don't know how the time-series characteristics of the distributed generator are considered.

One approach to the Reliability study would be to use a reliability model of the distribution system with failure rates and restore times for the various components. Another approach might be to start from the existing distribution reliability numbers and estimate how the distributed generator affects the outage rates and restoration times of the feeder.

These comments are based on the assumption that your concern is with the utility impacts at the distribution level. If you need to assess the impact at the transmission level, I would say that loss assessment will require a wider model of the transmission system so that you can see how the power injections at the generator bus affect flows in the rest of the system. I expect that choice of the slack bus would have a significant impact on the results. A simplified model such as you have diagrammed could be sufficient for studying voltage fluctuations and power quality at the point of interconnection to the transmission system.

I don't see how a distributed generator would have any impact on the reliability of the transmission system, so I'm not sure how you would do such a study at that level. I suppose that one could do an energy supply reliability study to see the impact of the new distributed generation, but to me that seems like a stretch for a case like this.